# For loop for multiple condition over Multiple conditions in single if statement

Tags: objective-c, for-loop

I had seen a code like this

```
if ([[dict objectForKey:@"name"] rangeOfString:@“AB”].location != NSNotFound ||
    [[dict objectForKey:@"name"] rangeOfString:@“CD”].location != NSNotFound ||
    [[dict objectForKey:@"name"] rangeOfString:@“EF”].location != NSNotFound ||
    [[dict objectForKey:@"name"] rangeOfString:@“GH”].location != NSNotFound ||
    [[dict objectForKey:@"name"] rangeOfString:@“IJ”].location != NSNotFound ||){
    // do something
   }
```

Which I changed to:

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@“AB”,
                @"CD", @"EF", @"GH", @"IJ", nil];

for (id object in myArray) {
    if ([[dict objectForKey:@"name”] rangeOfString: id].location != NSNotFound){
        // do something
        break;
    }
}
```

I understand readability is better after changing the code. Does it have any other advantages?

Comment: nothing that im aware of, but just being anal here, you should make your for loop like `for(String <#stringName#> in myArray)` rather, and if you want you can change `[dict objectForKey:@"name”]` to just `dict[@"name"]` but thats debatable whether thats more readable (less explicit, but less clutter which i prefer)

Comment: Why are you using the C tag?

Comment: I agree the code is written in Objective-c but I felt the use-case is applicable for c also. Will remove the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any substantial difference.  You could further improve readability and terseness by pulling the dictionary access out of the loop.

```
// probably done for you by the compiler, but still prettier to look at...
NSString *name = dict[@"name"];

for (id object in myArray) {
    if ([name rangeOfString:id].location != NSNotFound){
        // do something
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Agree. Minor note: The compiler can't do the optimization as the dict lookup is invisible to it and may have side effects.